# Show/Hide based on dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Jquery to show/hide divs based on what a user selects in a dropdown.

My HTML:

```
<select>
   <option value='test'>Test</option>
   <option value='example'>Example</option>
   <option value='blah'>Blah</option>
</select>
<div data-show="blah">Should be shown when blah</div>
<div data-hide="example">Should be hidden when example</div>
```

My Jquery (in coffeescript):

```
$("select").on "change", () ->
  shows = $('[data-show="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
  hides = $('[data-hides="' + $(this).val() + '"]')

  shows.show()
  hides.hides()
```

This works when a user chooses the right option, say *Example*. But when a user goes back to say *Test*, it should go back to the default. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Could you supply more info about the desired outcome. Do you want to hide all elements by detault and show only when the right selection has been made? And show some by default and only hide on a specific selection?

Comment: @Pilan. I want elements that have `data-hide` to be visible on default. When a user chooses the select option that matches `data-hide`, then the element should hide. Otherwise, the element should be shown.

Comment: @Pilan, and the opposite should be true for `data-show`

Comment: [got it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350867/show-hide-based-on-dropdown-option#51351022), i guess :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use `filter()` to set final display and do opposite on whole group before the filter

```js
$("select").on("change", function(){
  var value = this.value
  // hide all data-show
  $('[data-show]').hide().filter(function(){
     return $(this).data('show') === value;
  }).show()// only show matching ones
  
 $('[data-hide]').show().filter(function(){
     return $(this).data('hide') === value;
  }).hide()

}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value='test'>Test</option>
   <option value='example'>Example</option>
   <option value='blah'>Blah</option>
</select>
<div data-show="blah">Should be shown when blah</div>
<div data-hide="example">Should be hidden when example</div>
```

Comment: Hi @charlieftl, by default all the elements should hide, on change relating data element only showen, test has no data value

Comment: If that's the case do you really need both `data-show` and `data-hide`? Wouldn't one be sufficient?

Comment: NathanB is expecting if the user test everything should hide

Comment: @charlietfl, Thank you, this is the desired result. One question: If I were to have multiple selects on a page, each wrapped in: `<div class='select-picker'>`, what would be the easiest way to just filter elements for each `.select-picker` ?

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('.select-picker').find('[data-show]').hide().filter(function(){...`

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you are up to but this is the described behavior, probably not the desired :D

```js
$('select').on('change', (e) => {
  // apply defaults, then filter // credits to filter @charlietfl
  $('[data-show]').hide().filter('[data-show=' + $(e.target).val() + ']').show();
  $('[data-hide]').show().filter('[data-hide=' + $(e.target).val() + ']').hide();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value='test'>Test</option>
   <option value='example'>Example</option>
   <option value='blah'>Blah</option>
</select>
<div data-show="blah">Should be shown when blah</div>
<div data-hide="example">Should be hidden when example</div>
```

**EDIT** added default hide/show

Comment: Why would this work any differently. `e.target` and `this` are same

Comment: nope, `this` is `window` - try `console.log(this)` - if you do `function() {...}` `this` becomes `select`

Comment: OP is using coffee script not arrow function. That is true only in arrow function

Comment: sure but doesn't change any behavior

Comment: but the corrections i did do - like `data-hide` instead of `data-hides` - just wanted to provide a working example he can use as base

Answer (score 0):

Create a selection of your elements you want to show/hide:

```
var elements = $('[data-show], [data-hide]');
```

Then you can use jQuery's [**`.filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to show only the selected element:

```js
var elements = $('[data-show], [data-hide]');    

function showElement(option) {  
  var filter;  
  
  // hide all elements befor filtering
  elements.hide();
  
  // create the filter value, which will be used for filtering
  switch (option) {
    case 'test':
      filter = '[data-hide="example"]';
      console.log('show only example');
      break;
    
    case 'blah':
      filter = '*';
      console.log('show all elements');
      break;
      
    default:
      console.log('hide all elements (including example)');
      break;
  }  
  
  if (filter) {
    elements.filter(filter).show(); 
  }
}

showElement('test');

$("select").on("change", function() {
  showElement($(this).val());  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value='test'>Test</option>
  <option value='example'>Example</option>
  <option value='blah'>Blah</option>
</select>
<div data-show="blah">Should be shown when blah</div>
<div data-hide="example">Should be hidden when example</div>
```

Also you had several **typos**:

- When you select the element via `data-hide`, there's an additional `s` (`hides`):

  ```
  hides = $('[data-hides="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
  ```
- When you want to hide `hides` via calling `.hides()`, jQuery only has a `.hide()` function to hide an element:

  ```
  hides.hides()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="selectBoxClass">
    <option value='test'>Test</option>
    <option value='example'>Example</option>
    <option value='blah'>Blah</option>
</select>
<div data-show="blah" class="all ">Should be shown when blah</div>
<div data-hide="example" class="all">Should be hidden when example</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('change', '.selectBoxClass', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div.all').show();
        shows = $('[data-show="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
        hides = $('[data-hides="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
        shows.show()
        hides.hides()
    });

</script>
```

**if your previous code is not working well, then you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
            $('div').hide();
            $('select').change(function(){
                if($(this).val()=='blah'){
                  $('div[data-show]').show();
                  $('div[data-hide]').hide();

                }else if($(this).val()=='example'){
                  $('div[data-hide]').show();
                  $('div[data-show]').hide();
                }else{
                  $('div[data-hide]').hide();
                  $('div[data-show]').hide();
                }
            })
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select>
   <option value='test'>Test</option>
   <option value='example'>Example</option>
   <option value='blah'>Blah</option>
</select>
<div data-show="blah">Should be shown when blah</div>
<div data-hide="example">Should be hidden when example</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you assume a set of divs, some of which you wish to show/hide based on what you select in a dropdown list, in jQuery.

This is how it can be achieved.

**The grid**

```
<div class="row exhbitors-grid-row">
                            
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 exhibitor-grid-item" style="">
        <div class="exhibitor-grid-large wow pixFadeRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: pixFadeRight;">
            <div class="member-avater">
                <img src="#" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listing-page-exhibitor-brief wow pixFadeUp" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: pixFadeUp;">
                <div class="exhibitor-details">
                    <input type="hidden" name="industry" class="industry Accommodation" value="Accommodation">
                    <h4 class="grid-exhibitor-title">Tourist Board</h4>
                    <strong class="grid-exhibitor-copy">Manning the Booth</strong>
                    <div class="grid-item-host">
                        <span>User</span>
                        <a href="bcard.pdf" target="_blank" title="Download business card"><i class="fa fa-address-card b-card-file" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 exhibitor-grid-item" style="">
        <div class="exhibitor-grid-large wow pixFadeRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: pixFadeRight;">
            <div class="member-avater">
                <img src="#" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="listing-page-exhibitor-brief wow pixFadeUp" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: pixFadeUp;">
                <div class="exhibitor-details">
                    <input type="hidden" name="industry" class="industry Airline" value="Airline">
                    <h4 class="grid-exhibitor-title">Tourist Board</h4>
                    <strong class="grid-exhibitor-copy">Manning the Booth</strong>
                    <div class="grid-item-host">
                        <span>User</span>
                        <a href="bcard.pdf" target="_blank" title="Download business card"><i class="fa fa-address-card b-card-file" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
</div>
```

Somewhere on the page,you have a dropdown list which looks like this:

```
<select class="category-select" name="category-select" id="category-select">
    <option value="-1">Industry </option>
    <option value="1">Accommodation</option>
    <option value="2">Airline</option>
    <option value="3">Car Rentals</option>
    <option value="4">City Tourist Board</option>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</select>
```

On change of this dropdown list, we only want to show the div that has a hidden field value value same as the selected dropdown item. **Check the hidden field values above in the div**.

We need a small bit of jQuery to do the magic. This is how it will look:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(".category-select")){
$(".category-select").change(function(){
    $(".exhibitor-grid-item").show();
    var selectedIndustry = $(".category-select option:selected").text();
    $(".exhibitor-grid-item").each(function(){
        var $itemIndustry = $(this).find(".industry").val();
        if($(".category-select option:selected").val() > -1){
          if(selectedIndustry != $itemIndustry){
            $(this).find(".industry").parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
          }
        }
     });
   });
 }
});
```